# Exception with JPA/Hibernate when binding my entities to tables with @OneToMany annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Exception with Spring. When I try to bind my entities to tables with `@OneToMany` annotation.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne
>   on com.wumf.iModuleSyncApps.impl.IAppEntity.packageName references an
>   unknown entity: java.lang.String  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1598)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
>     ... 41 more

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IApp")
public class IAppEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="packageName")
    @Id
    private String packageName;

    private String icon;

    private String name;

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }

    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IAppsFriends")
public class IAppsFriends {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "packageName")
    private List<IAppEntity> apps;

    private String phone;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<IAppEntity> getApps() {
        return apps;
    }

    public void setPackageName(List<IAppEntity> apps) {
        this.apps = apps;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

Also I tried changing `@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="packageName")` to 
`@JoinColumnn(name="packageName")` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@ManyToOne` annotation is misplaced. You are annotating a `String` variable when you should be annotating a `IAppsFriends`:

```
@Table(name = "IApp")
public class IAppEntity {

    @Id
    private String packageName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="packageName")
    private IAppsFriends friends;

    // ... rest of code

}
```

You should also change `IAppsFriends` class to fix the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "friends")
private List<IAppEntity> apps;
```

Comment: Thanks, You really help me! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a OnwToMany relationship from `IAppEntity` to  `IAppsFriends`, you should store the id of `IAppsFriends` in the table `IApp`. The type of `IAppsFriends.id` is `int`. So I think you should get a right join column like `friends int(11) not null`.

Then JPA will depend on the value of column friends to get the instance IAppsFriends.

```
@Table(name = "IApp")
public class IAppEntity {

@Id
private String packageName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
private IAppsFriends friends;

// ... rest of code

}
```

PS: referencedColumnName means the reference in anther table. So the value should be id (the value of column friends should be one of the id of IAppsFriends)

Of course the code in IAppsFriends should modified to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "friends")
private List<IAppEntity> apps;
```